# Integrity error on django_admin_log after updating existing site to new Django 1.5 user model

Tags: django, django-1.5

Apparently after adding my new user table to the site, django_admin_log still has a FK to auth_user table.  Any way to address this? I didn't see this problem in staging or locally so something odd must have taken place.

**Traceback** (most recent call last) **:**

> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
>       response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.10.0.28/newrelic/api/object_wrapper.py", line 220, in **call**
>       self._nr_instance, args, kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.10.0.28/newrelic/hooks/framework_django.py", line 475, in wrapper
>       return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/options.py", line 372, in wrapper
>       return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
>       response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/cache.py", line 89, in _wrapped_view_func
>       response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 202, in inner
>       return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 25, in _wrapper
>       return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 91, in _wrapped_view
>       response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/decorators.py", line 21, in bound_func
>       return func(self, *args2, **kwargs2)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 223, in inner
>       return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 217, in **exit**
>       self.exiting(exc_value, self.using)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 281, in exiting
>       commit(using=using)
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/transaction.py", line 152, in commit
>       connection.commit()
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/**init**.py", line 241, in commit
>       self._commit()
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 242, in _commit
>       six.reraise(utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e.args)), sys.exc_info()[2])
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 240, in _commit
>       return self.connection.commit()
>
> File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/newrelic-1.10.0.28/newrelic/hooks/database_dbapi2.py", line 68, in commit
>       return self._nr_connection.commit()
>
> IntegrityError: insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint "django_admin_log_user_id_fkey"
>   DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(2) is not present in table "auth_user".

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That because the `django_admin_log` table still contains a foreign key relation to the old `auth_user` table.

You need to drop this and recreate the table.

```
$ heroku pg:psql
psql => drop table django_admin_log;
```

For Django < 1.7

```
$ heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

And for Django >= 1.7

```
$ ./manage.py sqlmigrate admin 0001 | heroku pg:psql
```

And that's it :)

> EDITED with @dustinfarris Django 1.7+ answer precision

Answer (score 37):

If you run into this and you're using >=1.7:

```
./manage.py dbshell

DROP TABLE django_admin_log;
```

and then:

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate admin 0001 | ./manage.py dbshell
```

Comment: Worked for me using 1.8.2. Would be best if you added what it actually does.

Comment: For a new project with `django 1.10.1`, I did the drop as noted, but instead of the `sqlimigrate` command at the end, I used a simple `migrate` command. So it was like "migrate->error->drop->migrate".

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it didn't work for me. It's throwing an error: "CommandError: Cannot find a migration matching '001' from app 'admin'. Is it in INSTALLED_APPS?"
Can you tell me what I did wrong ?

Answer (score 8):

If you are on Django 1.7 or later, adding a proper migration for altering the `django_admin_log` table is a much better option in my opinion. That way you can keep any existing log entries, which may actually be something you have use for. Doing such an alter requires that the id field is the same, e.g. has the same name etc.

First you will have to find out the name of the constraint, which can be done by going into the database shell:

```
./manage.py dbshell
```

And then describing the `django_admin_log` table:

```
\d+ django_admin_log;
```

This will have the constraint in the output, something like:

```
"user_id_refs_id_c0d12874" FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES my_custom_auth_model(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
```

Where `my_custom_auth_model` is the name of the table where your custom auth model lives, and `user_id_refs_id_c0d12874` is the name of the constraint, which you should copy for later.

Next, create a new migration:

```
./manage makemigrations --empty my_custom_auth_model
```

I renamed my new migration (i.e. `0000_alter_admin_log_constraint.py`) to have something useful instead of a datestamp in the filename. Don't use four zeros though, use whatever was assigned when creating the migration :)

In the new migration, this is what I used for operations:

```
operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL(
        '''ALTER TABLE django_admin_log DROP CONSTRAINT user_id_refs_id_c0d12874''',
        reverse_sql='''ALTER TABLE django_admin_log ADD CONSTRAINT user_id_refs_id_c0d12874
            FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES auth_user(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED'''),
    migrations.RunSQL(
        '''ALTER TABLE django_admin_log ADD CONSTRAINT user_id_refs_id_c0d12874
            FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES my_custom_auth_model(id) DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED''',
        reverse_sql='''ALTER TABLE django_admin_log DROP CONSTRAINT user_id_refs_id_c0d12874'''),
]
```

Substitute `user_id_refs_id_c0d12874` with whatever constraint name you copied previously. As you can see, the two operations and their reverses are inverses of each other, meaning you can move this migrations backwards as well.

Now, all you have to do is to apply the new migration:

```
./manage.py migrate
```

The `django_admin_log` table should now be usable again, and anything in admin writing to it will work instead of failing with an `IntegrityError`.

Comment: Not the easiest solution, but at least it saves your data in the admin log!

Comment: I don't think it's clean to hardcode the constraint names in the migration. This is not portable.

Comment: Thanks. I too feel having a migration file is way to have it this helped me

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though there may have been a bad transaction as some point when you ran this, you could try fully resetting your db with:

```
heroku pg:reset
```

Or you could attempt to psql into the database and examine/correct the data thats creating the issue (which is likely that its trying to insert the same user twice):

```
heroku pg:psql
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that admin app only installs django_admin_log table.

```
python manage.py sqlclear admin

BEGIN;
DROP TABLE "django_admin_log";

COMMIT;
```

So you can also try.

```
python manage.py sqlclear admin | python manage.py dbshell
python manage.py syncdb
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete the database and create a superuser, finally run `migrate`:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser    
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Deleting a database is not doable for some projects.