# IntegrityError at /admin/course/course/add/ in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-views, django-urls

I got this error when I tried to add content or course. It was working fine and now I get this error. I have uploaded it on heroku and it works fine, just in the local dev it won't add anything. Can someone explain whats going wrong. Pls also specify what additional info should I add ?

```
IntegrityError at /admin/course/course/add/

insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint "django_admin_log_user_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(2) is not present in table "auth_user".

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8888/admin/course/course/add/
Django Version:     1.5.1
Exception Type:     IntegrityError
Exception Value:    

insert or update on table "django_admin_log" violates foreign key constraint "django_admin_log_user_id_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(2) is not present in table "auth_user".

Exception Location:     /home/vagrant/sai/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py in _commit, line 240
Python Executable:  /home/vagrant/sai/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
```

Comment: Quick and dirty solution: reset your dev database.

Comment: @abstractpaper I'm not sure of the consequences..I'm still new django-dev.. Any clean soln. you might like to suggest

Comment: Resetting your development environment database should never have severe consequences. The only down side to doing this is creating a bunch of initial data all over again, which you can easily overcome with fixtures.

Comment: Have you tried logging out and in again?

Comment: @abstractpaper yup tried logging in n out.. I haven't tried fixtures yet..

Comment: @abstractpaper I'm not sure... will `python manage.py reset app_name` will do the work ?

Comment: `python manage.py flush`

Answer (score 6):

it is because you changed the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` after doing the first syncdb.

drop the table "django_admin_log".

then run `python manage.py syncdb`.

now "django_admin_log" is recreated with the correct reference to the AUTH_USER_MODEL.

Answer (score 0):

I just posted an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124523/integrity-error-on-django-admin-log-after-updating-existing-site-to-new-django-1/27028187#27028187) on doing this as a migration instead, which I think is a much better option:

[Integrity error on django_admin_log after updating existing site to new Django 1.5 user model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124523/integrity-error-on-django-admin-log-after-updating-existing-site-to-new-django-1/27028187#27028187)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same same issue but solved it in the following way:

1. I simply right-clicked on the SQLite3 folder in my root (base) directory and deleted it.
2. Confirmed the deletion
   Note: just make sure you are in the same directory that has the 'manage.py' file.
   That is, for example (in your terminal, the path points to: C:\users\your_username\desktop\your_project_name>
3. Ran python manage.py makemigrations
4. Next, I ran python manage.py migrate
5. Then ran python manage.py runserver
6. It was back on. I stopped the server (ctrl + c) so I could create admin logins.
7. And finally, I created login credentials using python manage.py createsuperuser

- I logged in to my django admin and it saved successfully what I was saving

Platform: Windows 10
IDE: Pycharm
Python version:3.10
Django version: 4.0

I trust this helps. All the best.