# How to drop `django_admin_log` with docker-compose?

Tags: django, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am using a docker-compose.yml file for my django app, and
I am trying to do `docker-compose run web python manage.py dbshell` and drop the table `django_admin_log` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25331238/3849293).

But this returned
`CommandError: You appear not to have the 'psql' program installed or on your path.`

How can I do `python manage.py dbshell` or drop the table `django_admin_log`?

Here is my docker-compose.yml

```
storage:
  image: busybox
  volumes:
    - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    - /data
  command: true

db:
  image: postgres
  environment:
     - POSTGRESQL_DB=postgres
     - POSTGRESQL_USER=postgres
     - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=password
  volumes_from:
    - storage

web:
  build: .
  environment:
    - DATABASE_HOST=postgres
  command: ./run_web.sh
  ports:
    - "80:80"
  links:
    - db
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using a Debian or Ubuntu-based image, in your Dockerfile, you just need to add the line:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install postgresql
```

That will install the psql command for you and allow you to use the dbshell.

Comment: Thanks.
But I don't want to install postgresql on 'web' container because the psql is installed on 'db' container...
Is there any good method to connect to 'db' container?

Comment: Actually you do; that is for installing the client, not the server. The web server needs to have the postgresql package in order to get the psql client.

Comment: Oh, I made a mistake...
I was able to use dbshell !
Thanks for your answer.

Comment: it's possible to install just the client `apt-get install -y postgresql-client`  (I'm on Ubuntu 14.04)